# Unable to run AppImage on Linux Mint Cinnamon 19

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Attempting to run it from the Terminal results in this:

```
heart@heart-desktop:~$ ./imagewriter-2.6.2-x86_64.AppImage
/tmp/.mount_imagewSmXTsZ/usr/bin/xdg-su: 601: /tmp/.mount_imagewSmXTsZ/usr/bin/xdg-su: xterm: not found
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried installing xterm?

Answer (score 0):

Install `xterm` from your distribution or request the AppImage to be fixed.